# Как на JavaScript распарсить строку

Tags: javascript

Как распарсить строку ? Есть строка вида

```
http://localhost:8080/#subscriptions/10/valid/20
```

Нужно вытянуть из нее два аргумента 10 и 20.

PS : Строка вводиться в браузер и на на выходе функции мы получаем только 10

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[github: URI Parsing with Javascript](https://gist.github.com/jlong/2428561#file-uri-js)

```js
parser = document.createElement('a');
parser.href = "http://localhost:8080/#subscriptions/10/valid/20";
    
hashArgs = parser.hash.split("/");

console.log(hashArgs[1], hashArgs[3]);
```

Comment: Что-то не получается. Может я неправильно передаю ? confirmSubscription: function(link) {

     var parser = document.createElement('a');
     var hashArgs = link.split("/");
     console.log(hashArgs[1], hashArgs[3]);

Comment: @Ivasoft, вы пропустили вторую строку из приведенного кода и использовали link вместо parser. Изучите код внимательней.

Comment: @ Alex Krass Вы невнимательно прочитали задание.  Строка вводиться в браузер а не задается явно.

Comment: @Ivasoft какая разница, Вы всегда можете ее достать через window.location. Да и с таким подходом код сократится до пары строк: `hashArgs = window.location.hash.split("/"); console.log(hashArgs[1], hashArgs[3]);`